# How to print in two different printers at the same time using PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, printing

I am developing a simple restaurant check-out system  in PHP where, once paid, both tickets must be printed, one for Kitchen and another one to client. The question is, i'm facing problem to print each ticket in 2 different printers. What is the best way to to that? Because I'm using JavaScript to print it, but this only work for one printer and I need to print **at the same time in both printers**.

**Obs:** both are installed via USB.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify: As this is a PHP/JavaScript application, I assume that it's web-based; ie you have a http server, and the terminals are running the system in a browser? From there, please confirm whether the printers are plugged into the terminal(s) or the server?

Answer (score 1):

Your web server can talk to the print server or printers and print it. You can't control how a web browser prints unless you have some kind of plugin.

Comment: If the printers are attached to the browser machine, then each user will need to have their own printers. It would probably be better to have the printers attached to the network, and print to them via the server. It'll be harder work because you'll need to format the page in the back-end rather than letting the browser do it for you, but that seems like a better solution to me, for a number of reasons (including that it resolves this problem). It will mean throwing away some code you've already written though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to solve using this library [link](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php). Now I can print in both printers locally through webpage.